# how to navigate page in outlook addins office 365

Tags: reactjs, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

i am trying to navigate page to next page in outlook addin . i was also install react router dom. but its not working in outlook addins.what is solution of navigate page to new page like login , signUp,ets .please help me about this issu.

[this is outlook addins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TyxN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the add-in needs to open a different page of the task pane you can use the `window.location.replace` method (or `window.location.href`) as the last line of the handler. The following example illustrates a possible solution:

```
function processMessage(arg) {
    // message processing code goes here;
    window.location.replace("/newPage.html");
    // Alternatively ...
    window.location.href = "/newPage.html";
}
```

Also you may try doing something like that:

```
window.open('https://yourwebsite.com')
```

Note, this should work if the domain is whitelisted in your manifest.